# Storing wooden doors in shed

Tags: storage, door, wood

We had someone else concrete garage as our storage but they had a water leak from the toilet upstairs and much of our stuff is going spoil, we took off the wooden doors as many people are in the house now and stored them. They are painted but now we have to move them in our Plastic shed for storage.

What is the best way to store a wooden door in the shed which doesn't have any climate control, so the door is in best space possible?

Comment: You should not let them sit directly on a soft base. Resting each on a couple of blocks will let air circulate allowing them dry a little more evenly.

Answer (score 1):

As with all wooden items, they should be stored flat with gaps all round for air flow to prevent warping. Propping against a wall will encourage warp as the wood soaks the moisture from the air and nothing supporting the middle from sagging.

Look at the storage section of https://www.intouch-quality.com/blog/wood-warping-and-how-to-prevent-it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is really a hack question, but the best way to store doors is upright (and they take up least room anyway).

The tops should be evenly supported by a wall, or the door could warp.

Depending on what the floor is made of, you must prevent damp rising into the wood. There may be a chance that your shed will leak too, so they should really be stored off the ground.

If there are several doors it will be convenient to stack them together, although they will stack better if you remove the handles (and store them in a bag or box). That way the doors will rest flat against each for full support.

If not, you could stack each door with its handles alternately at the left or the right, and slightly staggered so that the handles are beyond the edges of the door behind it. That might work better if the next pair of doors is stored upside-down, so their handles are at a different height from the pair behind, and will nest better. They can still be stood flat against each other without their handles colliding.

Finally, covering them with a sheet of plastic will help protect them.